# JavaScript sessionStorage in form validation

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have been working on designing a two page `login form` for few days. It has the following features

1. When user first enters the `domain name` in the browser, he will be displayed the `email page` where he has to enter his email id. If the email id is in my database (`csv file`), he will be sent to `password page`, otherwise not.
2. I declared a `session variable` in the `email page`. An `if condition` in the `password page` checks if this `session variable` is set. If this `session variable` is not set, he will be redirected to `email page`.
3. Main problem comes here
   If the user enters an email id which is in my database, he will be sent to the password page. If now     he copies the url of this `password page`, and pastes it in another tab, I want to redirect him to `email page` which I wasn't able to do.
   I thought of using `sessionStorage`. But I have no idea if the session variables gets carried to the next tab or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per the sessionStorage documentation, the values are not replicated across tabs.

- A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.
- Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
- Opening multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage for each tab/window.
- Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.

The documentation can be referred at,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

You can also use a global js variable to store the value instead of sessionStorage, but the variable value will be lost on page reload.

Comment: As per my experiment, I found that variables in ```sessionStorage``` will be over written when we reload the page. Is it true?

Comment: It will be flushed in case you close the tab and reopen. If you just reload the page it will not flush until and unless you overwrite/clear from code.